# Changing a vuex state from a different component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a component (modal) which relies on a store. The store has the state of the modal component - whether it is active or not.

I need to be able to call this modal to open from other components or even just on a standard link. It opens by adding an `.active` class.

How can I change the state of the store - either by calling the stores action or calling the modal components method (which is mapped to the store).

Modal Store:

```
class ModalModule {
    constructor() {
        return {
            namespaced: true,

            state: {
                active: false,
            },

            mutations: {
                toggleActive: (state) => {
                    return state.active = ! state.active;
                },
            },

            actions: {
                toggleActive({ commit }) {
                    commit('toggleActive');
                },
            },

            getters: {
                active: state => {
                    return state.active;
                }
            }
        };
    }
}

export default ModalModule;
```

Vue Component:

```
<template>
    <div class="modal" v-bind:class="{ active: active }">
        <div class="modal-inner">
            <h1>modal content here</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-close" v-on:click="this.toggleActive">
            X
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default {
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters('Modal', [
            'active',
        ])
    },
    methods: {
        ...mapActions('Modal', [
            'toggleActive',
        ]),
    }
}
</script>
```

And somewhere else I want to be able to have something like:

```
<button v-on:click="how to change the state??">OPEN MODAL</button>
```

Edit:

Here's the store:

```
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import ModalModule from './ModalModule'; 
class Store extends Vuex.Store {
    constructor() {

        Vue.use(Vuex);

        super({
            modules: {
                Modal: new ModalModule(),
            }
        });

    };
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need an action for your particular usecase . You just just define a mutation as you are just changing the boolean value of a property in a state. Actions are for async functionality. You usecase is just synchronous change of Boolean value

So you can do

```
<button v-on:click="$store.commit('toggleActive')">OPEN MODAL</button>
```

**EDIT:**
Just export a plain object

```
const ModalModule = {
            namespaced: true,

            state: {
                active: false,
            },

            mutations: {
                toggleActive: (state) => {
                    return state.active = ! state.active;
                },
            },

            actions: {
                toggleActive({ commit }) {
                    commit('toggleActive');
                },
            },

            getters: {
                active: state => {
                    return state.active;
                }
            }
}

export default ModalModule;// export the module
```

Even remove the `class` based definition of the store

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import ModalModule from './ModalModule'; 

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        ModalModule
    }
});
```

And change it like this in you component for mapping of the mutation (`<MODULE_NAME>/<MUTATION_NAME>`)

```
...mapMutations([
    'ModalModule/toggleActive' 
])
```

Comment: Thanks - I get unknown mutation type. How do I access the namespaced store module?

Comment: @panthro what is your modal module name when you defined it in the store?

Comment: "Modal" is it's name.

Comment: @panthro can you try `...mapMutations(['Modal/toggleActive'])`

Comment: I've mapped the mutations: 
unknown mutation type: toggleActive

Comment: @panthro well that's weird... can you show the code of store definition

Comment: @panthro looks fine... i'll try it on myself...and why use classes instead of plain object exports?

Comment: I missed a line: export default Store; It's just an examples ive seen really. Could you give me an example by what you mean by plain object exports?

Comment: @panthro ok i'lk add it in the answer and let you know

Comment: Thanks for the update, what are the pros/cons of doing class vs plain object?

Comment: @panthro i have never seen vuex store initialization with `class` syntax. So I do not know the pros/cons. As per  my view cons would be more verbose should call the constructor and `super()` call. Class is just syntactic sugar for object prototypal inheritance, since we do not define any methods for that object why use it?

Comment: So if we had some other non vue methods on it then class would be a good idea?

Comment: @panthro maybe but w may face the problem like you are facing now. You can create helper fumctions in the file you export your module if you ant to make use of any helper functions in your action or mutations

Answer (score 3):

You can access the store from your components via `this.$store`. There you can call your actions and mutations. So

```
<button v-on:click="$store.commit('your mutation name', true)">OPEN MODAL</button>
```

Comment: Thanks - how can I access an action? How can I access a namespaced store?

Comment: You can use dispatch. `this.$store.dispatch('your action name', payload)`. If it is namespaced you can just use its fully qualified name `this.$store.dispatch['some/nested/modules/actionName']`.

Comment: I get: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined

Comment: Are you using it inside a component?

Comment: $store is only injected on Vue components. So if you want to use store outside a component, you may have to manually import it: `import store from '/path/to/your/store'`. Then you can use `store.dispatch`.

Comment: I seem to be able to access it outside of a component via $store?

Comment: Oh. If so you should be able to use `v-on:click="$store.dispatch()"` right?

Comment: Yes but I think I am having issues because of my namespaced store.

Comment: Shouldn't you have `export default new Store()` at the end of your store file?

Comment: Yes it's there - I forgot to c+p it in.

Comment: I mean in your other comment you mentioned it was `export default Store`. It should be `export default new Store()`.

Comment: Yes! Anyway thanks for all your help with this - much appreciated.